# Sum x rows of dataframe and replace

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
                Date from             Date to  Actuals
4669  2017-12-22 06:00:00 2017-12-22 06:05:00       75
4670  2017-12-22 06:05:00 2017-12-22 06:10:00       81
4671  2017-12-22 06:10:00 2017-12-22 06:15:00       84
4672  2017-12-22 06:15:00 2017-12-22 06:20:00       78
4673  2017-12-22 06:20:00 2017-12-22 06:25:00       93
4674  2017-12-22 06:25:00 2017-12-22 06:30:00       93
4675  2017-12-22 06:30:00 2017-12-22 06:35:00       99
4676  2017-12-22 06:35:00 2017-12-22 06:40:00      102
4677  2017-12-22 06:40:00 2017-12-22 06:45:00      102
4678  2017-12-22 06:45:00 2017-12-22 06:50:00      108
4679  2017-12-22 06:50:00 2017-12-22 06:55:00      129
4680  2017-12-22 06:55:00 2017-12-22 07:00:00      135
4681  2017-12-22 07:00:00 2017-12-22 07:05:00      126
4682  2017-12-22 07:05:00 2017-12-22 07:10:00      111
4683  2017-12-22 07:10:00 2017-12-22 07:15:00       96
4684  2017-12-22 07:15:00 2017-12-22 07:20:00      111
4685  2017-12-22 07:20:00 2017-12-22 07:25:00      105
4686  2017-12-22 07:25:00 2017-12-22 07:30:00       99
4687  2017-12-22 07:30:00 2017-12-22 07:35:00      111
4688  2017-12-22 07:35:00 2017-12-22 07:40:00      129
4689  2017-12-22 07:40:00 2017-12-22 07:45:00      123
4690  2017-12-22 07:45:00 2017-12-22 07:50:00      138
4691  2017-12-22 07:50:00 2017-12-22 07:55:00      141
4692  2017-12-22 07:55:00 2017-12-22 08:00:00      156
4693  2017-12-22 08:00:00 2017-12-22 08:05:00      147
4694  2017-12-22 08:05:00 2017-12-22 08:10:00      120
4695  2017-12-22 08:10:00 2017-12-22 08:15:00       99
4696  2017-12-22 08:15:00 2017-12-22 08:20:00       75
4697  2017-12-22 08:20:00 2017-12-22 08:25:00       57
4698  2017-12-22 08:25:00 2017-12-22 08:30:00       45
                  ...                 ...      ...
53855 2018-10-08 03:30:00 2018-10-08 03:35:00        0
53856 2018-10-08 03:35:00 2018-10-08 03:40:00        0
53857 2018-10-08 03:40:00 2018-10-08 03:45:00        0
53858 2018-10-08 03:45:00 2018-10-08 03:50:00        0
53859 2018-10-08 03:50:00 2018-10-08 03:55:00        0
53860 2018-10-08 03:55:00 2018-10-08 04:00:00        0
53861 2018-10-08 04:00:00 2018-10-08 04:05:00        0
53862 2018-10-08 04:05:00 2018-10-08 04:10:00        0
53863 2018-10-08 04:10:00 2018-10-08 04:15:00        0
53864 2018-10-08 04:15:00 2018-10-08 04:20:00        0
53865 2018-10-08 04:20:00 2018-10-08 04:25:00        0
53866 2018-10-08 04:25:00 2018-10-08 04:30:00        0
53867 2018-10-08 04:30:00 2018-10-08 04:35:00        0
53868 2018-10-08 04:35:00 2018-10-08 04:40:00        0
53869 2018-10-08 04:40:00 2018-10-08 04:45:00        0
53870 2018-10-08 04:45:00 2018-10-08 04:50:00        0
53871 2018-10-08 04:50:00 2018-10-08 04:55:00        0
53872 2018-10-08 04:55:00 2018-10-08 05:00:00        0
53873 2018-10-08 05:00:00 2018-10-08 05:05:00        0
53874 2018-10-08 05:05:00 2018-10-08 05:10:00        0
53875 2018-10-08 05:10:00 2018-10-08 05:15:00        0
53876 2018-10-08 05:15:00 2018-10-08 05:20:00        0
53877 2018-10-08 05:20:00 2018-10-08 05:25:00        0
53878 2018-10-08 05:25:00 2018-10-08 05:30:00        0
53879 2018-10-08 05:30:00 2018-10-08 05:35:00        0
53880 2018-10-08 05:35:00 2018-10-08 05:40:00        0
53881 2018-10-08 05:40:00 2018-10-08 05:45:00        0
53882 2018-10-08 05:45:00 2018-10-08 05:50:00        0
53883 2018-10-08 05:50:00 2018-10-08 05:55:00        1
53884 2018-10-08 05:55:00 2018-10-08 06:00:00        0

[83324 rows x 3 columns]
```

I want to add rows so I get the cumulative value for each hour. Desired result:

```
             Date from             Date to  Actuals
1  2017-12-22 06:00:00 2017-12-22 07:00:00     1179
2  2017-12-22 07:00:00 2017-12-22 08:00:00     1157
                  ...                 ...      ...
1000 2018-10-08 05:00:00 2018-10-08 06:00:00      1
```

I tried this using `DataFrame.sum()` but I could only do this while summing the full colums and not subparts based on `datetime`. Any suggestions?

ps: In this case, there is a row in the dataframe for each 5 minutes. But I can imagine that this should be possible if that would not be the case.

EDIT: Using Statistic Dean's answer I found out that this is NOT a perfectly fille dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy route to take (although the structure of the output is not exactly the same with what you are asking, but easily manipulated) is to use `pandas.Grouper` to `groupby` the hour and then just sum the Actuals, i.e.

```
import pandas
import random

#Creating the data frame
d = pandas.date_range('2017-12-22 06:00:00', periods = 50, freq = '5min')
d1 = pandas.date_range('2017-12-22 06:05:00', periods = 50, freq = '5min')
d2 = random.sample(range(1000), 50)
df = pandas.DataFrame({'Date_From':d, 
                       'Date_To':d1, 
                       'Actuals':d2})

(df
  .set_index('Date_From')
  .groupby(pandas.Grouper(freq = 'H'))['Actuals']
  .sum())
```

which gives,

> ```
> Date_From
> 2017-12-22 06:00:00    5194
> 2017-12-22 07:00:00    5790
> 2017-12-22 08:00:00    5760
> 2017-12-22 09:00:00    6298
> 2017-12-22 10:00:00    1070
> Freq: H, Name: Actuals, dtype: int64
> ```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can notice is that you must sum 12 terms at a time. So one solution would be to go through your data frame, sum 12 terms at a time, take the start from from the first term and the stop from the last term. You just have to be careful about the boundaries. Let's call your dataframe df.

```
n = df.shape[0]//12 # The number of row you'll have
cumulative = np.zeros(n)
date_from = []
date_to = []
# Now go through the dataframe 12 steps at a time
for i in range(n):
    cumulative[i] = df.iloc[12*i:12*(i+1),2].sum() # Get the sum for the hour
    date_from.append(df.iloc[12*i,0]) # Get the starting instant
    date_to.append(df.iloc[12*i+11,1]) # Get the ending instant
# Now create your new dataframe
new_df = pd.DataFrame({Date_from: date_from, Date_to: date_to, Actuals: cumulative})
```

As i said earlier, this work only with the right boundaries(first row being the start of an hour), and goes to the last full hour.

Comment: Yes, this does work for a completely filled dataframe, as I said in the ps, a completely fille dataframe is desirable but often not reality. This also does not sum the values based on `datetime` but just on their index which implies that is it perfectly filled and inded starting from a full hour and ending on a full hour.

Comment: Ok, then what could be a solution would be to create a new column with the hour of the date interval. Then perform a groupby and sum on this column.